# Checking for existing child in OTP simple_on_for_one supervisor

Tags: erlang, mapreduce, erlang-otp

I'm writing an map/reduce word counter to learn OTP. I've created a simple_one_for_one supervisor that can start reducers. For every Key, I would like a  to check if there is already a child, if not, let the supervisor create the child.

I currently start childs in the supervisor module like this:

```
start_child(Key) ->
    supervisor:start_child(?SERVER, [Key]).
```

I would like to do something like this (untested):

```
start_child(Key) ->
    case supervisor:child_pid(Key) of
    Pid -> Pid;
    _ -> supervisor:start_child(?SERVER, [Key])
    end.
```

What is a good OTP way to find out if there is already a child for Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a supervisor that starts:

- A gen_server. Let's call it `reducer_server`
- A simple_one_for_one supervisor. Let's call it `reducer_sup`

Make sure your main supervisor starts `reducer_sup` before `reducer_server`. The state of `reducer_server` could be a dictionary of Key -> Pid pairs. `reducer_server` would then have a function like `reduce(Key)` which either finds the key in the dictionary and knows the corresponding process, or doesn't find the key and runs a function like:

```
new_reduce(Key) ->
    case supervisor:start_child(reducer_sup, [Key]) of
        {ok, Pid} when is_pid(Pid) -> {ok, Pid};
        {ok, Pid, _} when is_pid(Pid) -> {ok, Pid};
        _ -> error
    end.
```

Just add the resulting pid to your state and you should be ready for the next call to `reduce/1`. I'd recommend reading [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors) and [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-applications-with-otp) to get a better feel for how all of these parts work together. If you were putting this code into a production environment, you may want to consider things like:

- What happens when processes die? Hint: check for liveness with `is_process_alive/1`.
- What happens if either `reducer_server` or `reducer_sup` dies?